# SELECT DISTINCT + COUNT with some lastIndexOf?

Tags: php, sql

What I'm trying to do here is to extract the last part of a string. The strings always ends up the same way : thisismy-string. So i search for '-' in reverse to extract 'string' (which can be anything). ie: 'hello-world' to get 'world'

```
SELECT DISTINCT REVERSE(SUBSTR(REVERSE(field_name), 1, INSTR(REVERSE(field_name), '-')-1)) AS grp FROM table GROUP BY grp ORDER BY id
```

Which works fine. Now how can i count the number of times, SQL found the same 'end-of-string' while doing its DISTINCT function ? Is it possible to combine that in the same query ? I'm using this query for a PHP project...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS `occurrences`,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(`field_name`, '-', -1) AS `last_part`
FROM table
GROUP BY `last_part`
```

`SUBSTRING_INDEX([field or string], [delimiter], -1)` will get you the last part (due to the -1), and `COUNT()` respects grouping

Edit: Your title says something about "lastIndexOf", by which I assume you mean the highest `id` for each of the groupings. That you can do by adding `` MAX(`id`) `` to the fields you're selecting

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS `occurrences`,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(`field_name`, '-', -1) AS `last_part`,
    MAX(`id`) AS `last_index_of`
FROM table
GROUP BY `last_part`
```

---

Example

```
id  | field_name
------------------------
1   | foo-bar
2   | woo-bar
3   | woo-foo-baz
4   | foo-foo
5   | foo-boo
6   | foo-bar
7   | foo-baz
8   | kung-foo
9   | xyz-xyz
10  | 123-xyz
```

Result:

```
occurrences | last_part | last_index_of
----------------------------------------
3           | bar       | 6
2           | baz       | 7
1           | boo       | 5
2           | foo       | 8
2           | xyz       | 10
```

Comment: This only gives me 1 'last_part' where my query return all the last parts. Something i'm missing ?

Comment: @Eric: Not sure I understand what you mean by "only 1 last part"? Testing it on my own DB, it seems to do what you need. Could you maybe edit your answer to give a more comprehensive example of the data you have and the results you want?